# R and cor function

Tags: r

I have written this code in R REPL

```
content <- read.csv("[001.csv][1]", header=TRUE)
head(content, n=5L)
cc <- subset(content, !is.na(sulfate) & !is.na(nitrate))
head(cc, n = 5L)
cor <- cor(cc[2], cc[3])
print(cor)

head(content, n=5L)

#         Date sulfate nitrate ID 
#1  2003-01-01      NA      NA  1 
#2  2003-01-02      NA      NA  1 
#3  2003-01-03      NA      NA  1 
#4  2003-01-04      NA      NA  1 
#5  2003-01-05      NA      NA  1 

head(cc, n=5L)

#          Date sulfate nitrate ID             
#279 2003-10-06    7.21   0.651  1             
#285 2003-10-12    5.99   0.428  1             
#291 2003-10-18    4.68   1.040  1             
#297 2003-10-24    3.47   0.363  1             
#303 2003-10-30    2.42   0.507  1

print(cor)

#           nitrate
#sulfate -0.2225526
```

I wonder why does it say `nitrate sulfate -0.2225526` rather than just `-0.2225526`.

it seems to me that the `cor` function is not able to understand the difference between the row and the header? or is it something else....

The output which I expected was just `-0.2225526` and not `nitrate sulfate -0.2225526`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what the issue is, but if the result is a matrix, with row and column names, you can use `unname` to drop the names. Also, note that by doing `cor <- cor(cc[2], cc[3])`, you have masked the `cor` function in your working environment, which is a Bad Idea.

Comment: Oh my bad! didn't realize that the output was a matrix. Sorrry!